# using gitlab application with self hosted versions of gitlab

Tags: oauth, gitlab

I'm creating a gitlab application that I want all gitlab users to use wether on gitlab's cloud or their self-hosted version of gitlab.

I'm following these guides:

- [GitLab as OAuth2 authentication service provider](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/oauth_provider.html)
- [GitLab as an OAuth2 provider](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/oauth2.html#gitlab-as-an-oauth2-provider)

So I created my application on gitlab.com and got the app id, I made the oauth url

```
https://gitlab.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=6b7979bc2dbd78444592e30d624aa37fc0fc2c9145f3af44f1f70f5c4adbf21d&redirect_uri=http://redirect.url/example&response_type=code&state=your_unique_state_hash
```

[image]

and it works (notice that the above url is from gitlab where the app is made), now when I try to access that same url but for a self-hosted gitlab

```
https://gitlab.project.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=6b7979bc2dbd78444592e30d624aa37fc0fc2c9145f3af44f1f70f5c4adbf21d&redirect_uri=http://redirect.url/example&response_type=code&state=your_unique_state_hash
```

[image]

#### So how can I make an app that works for self-hosted gitlab as well?

Comment: Is your self hosted version accessible from the internet ? Does it have a proper public URL ?

Comment: @CCH yes, its totally accessible, the url doesn't have ports, its a subdomain of my domain just like in the example in the question

Comment: Maybe it's not supported for self hosted gitlab server. Could you share it if you have already figured it out?